# How to get the entire row of a dataframe based on the most recent date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, max

I do not have much experience working with pandas dataframes but I have this code:

```
myAAPL = Testdf.loc["AAPL"]

print(myAAPL)
```

and it produces:

```
        date                             ...      quantity    average_price
symbol                                                  
AAPL    2020-12-31T14:28:48.019000Z      ...      1.0         134.01
AAPL    2020-10-28T19:57:59.169000Z      ...      1.0         111.24
AAPL    2020-10-08T16:48:35.459000Z      ...      4.0         115.34
AAPL    2020-10-01T13:05:07.388000Z      ...      4.0         117.58
AAPL    2020-09-03T13:13:01.069000Z      ...      1.0         127.29
AAPL    2020-02-28T14:30:06.407000Z      ...      2.0         257.49
AAPL    2020-01-03T16:36:38.132000Z      ...      2.0         298.63
```

I want to get and remove the most recent row (by date/time). I am thinking I can use "pop" to do this? But I don't know how. I tried:

```
myAAPL = Testdf.loc["AAPL"].max()
```

But this didn't quite work. It returned the maximum value from each column. I basically need to find the most recent date and get the date, the quantity and the average price for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply slice the dataframe to drop the first row. Assuming that the dataframe is already sorted correctly:

```
myAAPL = Testdf.loc["AAPL"][1:]
```

otherwise:

```
myAAPL = Testdf.loc["AAPL"].sort_values(by='date',ascending=False)[1:]
```

Comment: Thank you... This was helpful